# Next.js and auth.js, callbakrouteerror

Tags: next.js, next-auth

js with auth.js I'm using credentials provider and I'm getting this error when deploying app in server.

However in localhost there are no errors.

login page looks like this

```
'use client'

import { Label } from '@/components/ui/label'
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button'
import * as z from 'zod'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormMessage } from '@/components/ui/form'
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input'
import { FormError } from '@/components/utility/FormError'
import { LoginChema } from '@/schemas/LoginSchema'
import { login } from '@/actions/login'
import { useState, useTransition } from 'react'

export const LoginTab = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | undefined>('')
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition()

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof LoginChema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(LoginChema),
    defaultValues: {
      login: '',
      password: ''
    }
  })

  async function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof LoginChema>) {
    setError('')

    startTransition(() => {
      login(values).then((data) => {
        setError(data?.error)
      })
    })

  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className='flex flex-col gap-6'>
        <div className='flex w-full flex-col gap-2'>
          <Label htmlFor='login_type' className='text-base tracking-tight'>
            Login/Parolni kiriting
          </Label>
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name='login'
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Login</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input disabled={isPending} placeholder='login' {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name='password'
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Parol</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input disabled={isPending} type='password' placeholder='parol' {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
        </div>
        <FormError message={error} />
        <div className='flex w-full flex-col gap-3'>
          <Button disabled={isPending} type='submit' className='w-full bg-brandHighlight-500 text-white'>
            Kirish
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

login action looks like this:

```
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'

import { AuthError, NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth'
import { LoginChema } from '@/schemas/LoginSchema'

const baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + '/users/login'

export default {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const validatedFields = LoginChema.safeParse(credentials)

        if (validatedFields.success) {
          const { login, password } = validatedFields.data

          const res = await fetch(baseURL, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
              username: login,
              password
            }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
          })

          if (!res.ok) {
            throw new AuthError('CredentialsSignin')
          }

          const user = await res.json()

          if (!user) return null

          return user
        }

        return null
      }
    })
  ]
} satisfies NextAuthConfig
```

and auth file like this:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import authConfig from '@/auth.config'

export const {
  handlers: {
    GET, POST
  }, auth,
  signIn,
  signOut
} = NextAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: 'auth/login',
    error: '/auth/error'
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.access_token = token.access_token
      session.user.username = token.username
      session.user.role = token.role

      return session
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.access_token = user.access_token
        token.username = user.username
        token.role = user.role
      }

      return token
    }
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
    maxAge: 8 * 60 * 60
  },
  ...authConfig
})
```

> [auth][error] CallbackRouteError: Read more at
> https://errors.authjs.dev#callbackrouteerror [auth][cause]: TypeError:
> fetch failed
> at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12344:11
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async globalThis.fetch (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/198.js:6:55448)
> at async Object.authorize (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/app/auth/login/page.js:1:114277)
> at async Object.l (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/763.js:6:181609)
> at async u (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/763.js:6:195182)
> at async u (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/763.js:6:174759)
> at async o (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/763.js:358:58635)
> at async r (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/app/auth/login/page.js:1:11856)
> at async /root/projects/shaffof-open-data/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:406
> [auth][details]: {   "code": "CERT_HAS_EXPIRED",   "provider":
> "credentials" } o: Read more at
> https://errors.authjs.dev#callbackrouteerror
> at Object.l (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/763.js:6:182434)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async u (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/763.js:6:195182)
> at async u (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/763.js:6:174759)
> at async o (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/763.js:358:58635)
> at async r (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/app/auth/login/page.js:1:11856)
> at async /root/projects/shaffof-open-data/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:406
> at async rg (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:15:6309)
> at async rz (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:24709)
> at async doRender (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1394:30)
> {   type: 'CallbackRouteError',   kind: 'error',   [cause]: {
> err: TypeError: fetch failed
> at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12344:11
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async globalThis.fetch (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/198.js:6:55448)
> at async Object.authorize (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/app/auth/login/page.js:1:114277)
> at async Object.l (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/763.js:6:181609)
> at async u (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/763.js:6:195182)
> at async u (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/763.js:6:174759)
> at async o (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/chunks/763.js:358:58635)
> at async r (/root/projects/shaffof-open-data/.next/server/app/auth/login/page.js:1:11856)
> at async /root/projects/shaffof-open-data/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:406
> {
> cause: [Error]
> },
> code: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED',
> provider: 'credentials'   }

Answer (score -1):

```
Actually, the issue is from your API, If you notice your next-auth error log it complains as mentioned below, 

{ cause: [Error] }, code: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED', provider: 'credentials' }

To see your actual error, try to add catch block inside authorize/ activate the logger from next auth.

1.May be your server does not have a valid certificate
2.Check your AUTH_URL & API URL for the hosted server, may be mistyped
```